# Free Pascal IDE: Writeln and Readln don't work properly

Tags: io, console, freepascal

Using the Free Pascal IDE, I have some problems with console IO under Windows.

When I use Writeln the cursor doesn't move to the next line and is staying at the end of the written line. So if I press Enter instead of moving to the next line the cursor goes to the beginning of the current line. And if I use Readln after Writeln new characters that I enter are displayed instead of the characters that were written with Writeln.

When I use Readln to enter string I have next problem. If I enter some string, use backspace to delete characters and enter other characters after that, Readln return to program string that includes backspace symbols and deleted characters.

I guess this is Windows problem, but I have no ideas.

Comment: How can this be reproduced?

Comment: @David: Start any console program with the FPC IDE (the simple on that comes with FPC and looks a little like Turbo Pascal) on Windows 10.

Comment: @Rudy Could you edit the question please, because then there is value

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks as if you have run into a (known) problem with the Free Pascal IDE on Windows 10. This happens to console programs started from that IDE. There is no fix, and no workaround (well, there is one: use unit `Crt`). It has other issues as well.

Just try another IDE, e.g. Lazarus.

Note that your program will run fine if started standalone. But not when started from the FPC IDE.

Comment: It's a known problem, but it doesn't appear on every computer with Windows 10. I have a laptop with this OS and Free Pascal works just fine. There is value in this question, though.